How to rerender server component after redirection
I have a server component that fetches data and displays it, only when the user is authorized:
function FirstServerComponent() {
  const isAuth = // checking if user authorized

  return (
    <div>
      {isAuth ? (
        <SecondServerComponent/>
      ): (
        <p>unauthorized</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

In the header of my page there is a button that starts oauth authorization flow, and then redirects back to our page and setting our isAuth state to true.
How do I rerender FirstServerComponent so it can render SecondServerComponent?

You will use two things for this:
NextJS - Routing Redirection
NextJS - Loading UI and Streaming
Here is an example of usage:
Folder structure
app
   [route]
      component/server-component.jsx
      page.jsx
      loading.jsx

page.jsx (server component)
"use server";

import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { SecondServerComponent } from "./component";

function sleep() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 2000);
    });
}

export default async function Page() {
    const isAuthenticated = await sleep(); //Checking...

    if (!isAuthenticated) {
        redirect("/app/login");
        // or
        // return <div>unauthorized</div>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <SecondServerComponent />
        </div>
    );
}

loading.jsx (client component)
export default function LoadPage() {
    return <div>Validating User</div>;
}

server-component.jsx (server component)
export async function SecondServerComponent() {
    const data = await getData() // getting data...
    return <div>Server Component {String(typeof window === "undefined")}</div>;
}

